# Putting int variable into Array

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino, associative-array

So I got an Arduino for Christmas and made a simple 3 LED circuit and made a 2 animations for it.

I want to make the code cleaner and add the possibility for the animation to work with any LEDs without adding more code to the animation function.

A way I thought of doing this (I've never used C++/C#) is using an array/dictionary that stores the variables of the LEDs, and making the LEDs light up by looping through the array/dictionary. How would I do this? Is it even possible?

I've currently got this:

```
std::map<std::char, std::int> x = {{led, 9}, {led2, 6}, {led3, 5}};
```

the `int` being where the jumper cable for the LED is plugged into.

Sorry if this is all stupid and ugly, like I said, I've never used C#/C++, I've only ever used RBX, Lua and Python.

Comment: `std::map<char,int>`

Comment: What are `led`, `led2` etc.?  Depending on the answer to that basic question, the answer to the posted question might be: `std::map<std::string, std::int> x = {{"led", 9}, {"led2", 6}, {"led3", 5}};` or might be what dasblinkenlight suggested or might be some other similar change.

Comment: Are you using C++ or C#?  They are different languages.  The C# has garbage collection, and no pointers.  The C++ language does not have garbage collection and can use pointers for accessing hardware registers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, congrats on the Arduino - it's great for learning.

> I've currently got this:
>
> `std::map<std::char, std::int> x = {{led, 9}, {led2, 6}, {led3, 5}};`

You don't need all this for animating some LED's on the Arduino. You can just use a byte-array or vector to store the **pin-numbers** where your LED's are connected, and start an animation based on these values. Or if you would like to reference them with for example Green_led1, Blue_led1, .. you can use an **enum** where the values would represent the positions in your vector/array. But it's better no to use strings (or char) for that.

Since **space is limited on Arduino**, it might be best to get used to using the smallest possible datastructures (in this case 1 byte per LED, the enums won't take space).

But you could even do better, for some more fun:

Depending on the type of Arduino you have, you could be using an `8-bit PORT` directly. That way each bit in that byte would represent the On/Off status of the corresponding LED. But more interesting is the ability to write the whole byte at once to the `PORT`. To animate, you could use bit-shifting. Just be aware that the Arduino pin-numbers are not the same as the pin-numbers on your [**AVR-chip**](http://www.atmel.com/devices/atmega328.aspx?tab=overview).

Answer (score 1):

```
std::map<std::string, std::int> x = {{"led", 9}, {"led2", 6}, {"led3", 5}};
```

or use an enum for the leds or just numbers

Answer (score 1):

You can code as following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    enum LedType {
      LedInvalid = 0,
      LedOne = 9,
      LedTwo = 6,
      LedThree = 5,
    };

    std::map<LedType, int> x = { { LedOne, 9 }, { LedTwo, 6 }, { LedThree, 5 } };
    printf("%d %d %d\n", x[LedOne], x[LedTwo], x[LedThree]);
}
```